# Creating new Stock List Item does not open Materialize Modal, but initial state items work

Tags: reactjs, api, typeerror, dispatch

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. Excited to be a part of the community!

I am creating a Stock Market App project. I ran into an interesting problem. I am using Materialize in my project over Bootstrap. I am coding in React. I have 2 stocks in my initial state, Apple and FaceBook. Whenever I click on them, the modal opens with more stock info on each. But whenever I add a new stock (like JPM), the item shows up, but whenever I click, it will not open.

### In materialize, you initialize the modal with jquery like below in (index.html). Then you make the href and ID match on each item like I did. I inspected the new like created for JPMorgan and it says href="#JPM" and id="JPM" just like the others that work. The only thing I can think of is that maybe whenever the jquery initializes, that when I add an item, it is somehow not initialized as well? But I'm not sure about that because it is just a simple line of code:

### $('.modal').modal();

Def pretty stumped here. The github repository is below. I'll also post some screen shots of my StockItem.js file. https://github.com/Christopher-Bowling/Stock-Market-App

Pictures:
[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E6xI.jpg) [StockItem.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Yni.jpg)

Comment: No idea why part of my post is bold btw haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the component initialisation each time you create a new element that needs initialising.

When you run $('.modal').modal(), jQuery looks for any element in the dom and runs the .modal() function on it - once. Any dynamically added elements (added after this initial has run) will behave as if you never ran the init at all. It is touched upon on the select doc page:

> **Initialization**
>
> In addition, you will need a separate call for any dynamically
>   generated select elements your page generates.You must initialize the select element as shown below.

https://materializecss.com/select.html

Comment: Thank you for replying and confirming the problem. Now I can zero in on the solution! Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue? I've been trying different ideas for a few hours and nothing has worked. I even woke up in the night and tried a few things suspecting that that was the problem and didn't get any of it to work haha.

Comment: anytime there's a re-render, you need ti re-init. So use the vanilla js method i guess.

Comment: Cool. I figured it out. In the Individual StockItem.js file, I added this and imported "import M from 'materialize-css':                                                                            
                                                                                   
  useEffect(() => {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
      M.Modal.init(elems);
  },);